# How to insert a variable into a Laravel Blade Template that is inside a HTML href tag for a web.root link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to creating a blog post with Laravel using views (`blog.blade.php`) inside HTML.

The code in my laravel web.php fetches the blog posts from my local mssql server looks as follow (and works):

```
Route::get('/blog/{id}', function($id){
$posts = DB::table('blog_posts')->get();
return view('blog', ['id'=>$id], ['posts'=>$posts]); });
```

In the laravel views dir home.blade.php my code works with hardcoded route: url('/blog/1')
The href link takes you to the full blog post

```
<h2>Blog posts:</h2>
@foreach ($posts as $post)  
    <p>{{ $post->title }} </p> <a href="{{ url('/blog/1') }}" >&#9650; Click here to view full post</a>
@endforeach
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
<p>{{ $post->title }} </p> <a href="{{ url('/blog/{{ $post->id }}') }}" >&#9650; Click here to view full post</a>
```

How do I get the `$post->id` that is the route (1, 2, 3 or 4) and comes from the sql data base saved to the blog row to work. I get the following error returned from my xampp php server when using `{{ $post->id }}` instead of hardcoding "1" .

> D:\XAMPP Server\htdocs\cool-blog
> ParseError
> Unclosed '(' does not match '}' (View: D:\XAMPP Server\htdocs\cool-blog\resources\views\home.blade.php)
> http://localhost:8000/

Answer (score 1):

Pass second param to `url()` method

```
<p>{{ $post->title }} </p> <a href="{{ url('blog',$post->id) }}" >&#9650; Click here to view full post</a>
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url

Comment: Thank you, Excellent solution that does not produce a IDE syntax error.  I did not know more that one parameter could be passed to url() method.

Comment: I did not know this as well. So double the thank you :)

Comment: and for many params is <a href="{{ route('route.name', ['param1'=>$val1, 'param2'=> $val2]) }}">

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p>{{ $post->title }} </p> <a href="{{ url('/blog/'.$post->id.'') }}" >&#9650; Click here to view full post</a>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for me! Simple solution to the problem.